# How do I apply CSS attributes by object id in GTK4?

Tags: css, gtk, gtkbuilder, gtk4

I am learning GTK4 from scratch, using GTKBuilder XML to construct objects and CSS to add style information from a file using:

```
const char cssPath[] = "/a/path/that/is/confirmed/to_be/working.css";
GtkCssProvider * cssProvider = gtk_css_provider_new();
gtk_css_provider_load_from_path(cssProvider, cssPath);
gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_display(gdk_display_get_default(), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(cssProvider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
```

When I use a generic CSS selector my style changes take affect, like so:

```
box { background-color: white; }
/* box goes white as expected */
```

but when I try and target a specific object using it's id="myBox" XML attribute, it doesn't work:

```
box#myBox { background-color: white; }
/* no colour change happens */
```

or

```
#myBox { background-color: white; }
/* no colour change happens here either */
```

The relevant section from my XML .ui file is:

```
    <object class="GtkBox" id="myBox">
        <property name="halign">GTK_ALIGN_CENTER</property>
        <child>

            <object class="GtkLabel" id="centreLabel">
                <property name="single-line-mode">true</property>
                <property name="xalign">0</property>
                <property name="yalign">0.5</property>
            </object>
        </child>
    </object>
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the way CSS selectors work, relative to the objects instantiated using GtkBuilder? I've read the docs, so I would appreciate any help anyone can offer here!

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `name` property in the UI file, you can set the specific Css name that you want your `<object>` to have. In order for this custom name to be used, you also need to put `#` in front of the `myBox` name in the Css, which you have already done.

To define the `name` property, simply add this line under your Box object in your UI file:

```xml
<property name="name">myBox</property>
```

Here is what your UI file should look like:

```xml
    <object class="GtkBox" id="myBox">
        <property name="halign">GTK_ALIGN_CENTER</property>
        <property name="name">myBox</property>
        <child>

            <object class="GtkLabel" id="centreLabel">
                <property name="single-line-mode">true</property>
                <property name="xalign">0</property>
                <property name="yalign">0.5</property>
            </object>
        </child>
    </object>
```

And here is what the Css should look like (you already had it this way):

```css
#myBox { background-color: white; }
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked straight away. It's always a simple answer isn't it ‍♂️

Comment: I'm only new to GTK but this feels like an area where the documentation assumes a lot about what you already know and never actually says it. Hmmm, I wonder if they take documentation PRs...

Comment: Glad to help! I only just discovered how to do this today; I figured it out looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16740949/16775594), which is about something related. I don't know anything about C, so I'm glad that this didn't require C code to answer ;-)! It took me a while to figure out the the property was `name`; the Python methods that change this are called `set_css_name()` and `get_css_name()`, so I assumed at first that the property was something like `css-name`...

Answer (score 0):

I just got done going through this with GTK3.  Horrible documentation.

Anyway, I had the exact same problem as you, and the solution was to ignore the GTK documentation (go figure).

You need the following to reference named nodes, I will use your example:

```
box#myBox { background-color: white; }
```

Change to:

```
#myBox box{ background-color: white; }
```

This solution was not listed anywhere on the GTK website.